# Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.4.38-std-1

Tags: 16.04, linux-headers

I try to install the headers to be able to get vboxdrv working but I get the following error:

```
Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.4.38-std-1
```

Comment: Please share some more detail about the procedure.

Comment: Which *exact* command did you run to get that output? Why do you have such a strange kernel version string? What's the output of `uname -a` and `dpkg-query -l linux-image-\* | grep '^i'`?

Answer (score 0):

The kernel version `4.4.38-std-1` is not a supported Ubuntu version.

Obviously there is no corresponding headers package in Ubuntu repositories.

You need to get the headers from the place where you got the kernel from, or install a supported Ubuntu kernel.